# C# - How to add X minutes to current UNIX timestamp

Tags: c#

This is how I'm getting my current UNIX timestamp.

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

How can I add on 10 minutes on this current UNIX timestamp, and have it still be formatted as a UNIX timestamp.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could just add 10 * 60 onto it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AddMinutes(x)`.

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

In php:

```
<?php
    $inTenMinutes = time() + 10 * 60;
?>
```

Comment: How ironic, "You can accept the answer in 10 minutes.", but anyway thank you.

Comment: Um do you know how to this on PHP?

Comment: `Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds + 600; ` works too...

Comment: Any ideas on how to dis this in PHP as well?